# Which ContentType to use for streaming file to view in browser?

Tags: asp-classic, stream, mime-types, content-type, adodb

I am trying to stream a file to the browser using adodb.

The user gets an option like this:

---

[image]

---

The `Save File` option works as expected.

But the `Open with Firefox` option gives gobbledy, and .htm is appended to the end of the filename.

I presumed that this had to do with the setting for `Response.ContentType`.

I have tried using `application/pdf`, `application/octet-stream` and `application/x-unknown`.  But whichever I use, I always get the same result.

*What is going on here? What ContentType should I be using?*

---

**Shot of Open With Firefox**

[image]

---

**ADODB Stream Code**

```
Dim objStream
Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = 1 
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile(fileDirectory & "\" & fileToDownload)

Response.AddHeader "Expires", "0"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary" 
Response.AddHeader "Content-Description", "File Transfer" 
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fileToDownload
Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", objStream.Size 
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
Response.ContentType = "???"  // *** what should I put here? ***
Response.BinaryWrite objStream.Read
objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as having `Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"`, I also needed to have `Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "application/pdf"`.

So the final code, that worked, was:

```
Dim objStream
Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile(fileDirectory & "\" & fileToDownload)

Response.AddHeader "Expires", "0"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary" 
Response.AddHeader "Content-Description", "File Transfer" 
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fileToDownload
Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", objStream.Size 
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "application/pdf" '** added this line **
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.BinaryWrite objStream.Read
objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing
```